# Check If User Followed Account, Without Using SoundCloud API

Tags: php, html, api, oauth, soundcloud

Since *SoundCloud* hasn't been accepting API applications for the past year, I need to find an alternate method to do this. Can anyone help?

Using [Powerful Exchange System Pro](http://mn-shop.com/powerful-exchange-system-pro), clicking a "follow" button on a user pops up their *SoundCloud* profile. Then, it checks if you've followed the *SoundCloud* user after closing the window.

Is there a way to check this without having an approved SoundCloud app/applicationID/secret?